# Communication of parallel processes: what are my options?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, shared-memory, snowfall

I'm trying to dig a bit deeper into parallelziation of R routines.

What are my options with respect to the communication of a bunch of "worker" processes regarding

1. the communication **between** the respective **workers**?
2. the communication of the **workers** with the "**master**" process?

AFAIU, there's no such thing as a "**shared environment/shared memory**" that both the master as well as all worker processes have access to, right?

The best idea I came up with so far is to base the communication on reading and writing JSON documents to the hard drive. That's probably a bad idea ;-) I chose `.json` over `.Rdata` files because JSON seems to be used for inter-software communication a lot, so I thought to go with that "standard".

Looking forward to learning about better options!

FYI: I'm usually parallelizing based on functions of the base package **parallel** and the contrib package [snowfall](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html&ei=toAJUI-0FMr-4QS3uKzjCg&usg=AFQjCNH42-QAPtX-Qk0UDXlm9VHkTtuW3A&sig2=_SRREm2wPQ7Pk441O47STQ), mainly relying on function `sfClusterApplyLB()` to get the job done

### EDIT

I should have stated that I'm running on Windows, but Linux-based answers/hints are also very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For communication between processes, a kind of fun place to start is the help page `?socketConnections` and the code in the chunk marked "## Not run:". So start an R process and run

```
 con1 <- socketConnection(port = 6011, server=TRUE)
```

This process is acting as a server, listening on a particular port for some information. Now start a second R process and enter

```
 con2 <- socketConnection(Sys.info()["nodename"], port = 6011)
```

con2 in process 2 has made a socket connection with con1 on process 1. Back at con1, write out the R object `LETTERS`

```
writeLines(LETTERS, con1)
```

and retrieve them on con2.

```
readLines(con2)
```

So you've communicated between processes without writing to disk. Some important concepts are also implicit here, e.g., about blocking vs. non-blocking connections, It is not limited to communication on the same machine, provided the ports are accessible across whatever network the computers are on. This is the basis for `makePSOCKcluster` in the parallel package, with the addition that process 1 actually uses the `system` command and a script in the parallel package to start process 2. The object returned by `makePSOCKcluster` is sub-settable, so that you can dedicate a fraction of your cluster to solving a particular task. In principle you could arrange for the spawned nodes to communicate with one another independent of the node that did the spawning.

An interesting exercise is to do the same using the fork-like commands in the `parallel` package (on non-Windows). A high-level version of this is in the help page `?mcparallel`, e.g.,

```
 p <- mcparallel(1:10)
 q <- mcparallel(1:20)
 # wait for both jobs to finish and collect all results
 res <- mccollect(list(p, q))
```

but this builds on top of lower-level `sendMaster` and friends (peak at the `mcparallel` and `mccollect` source code).

The Rmpi package takes an approach like the `PSOCK` example, where the manager uses scripts to spawn workers, and with communication using mpi rather than sockets. But a different approach, worthy of a weekend project if you have a functioning MPI implementation, is to implement a script that does the same calculation on different data, and then collates results onto a single node, using commands like `mpi.comm.rank`, `mpi.barrier`, `mpi.send.Robj`, and `mpi.recv.Robj`.

A fun weekend project would use the parallel package to implement a work flow that involved parallel computation but not of the mclapply variety, e.g., where one process harvests data from a web site and then passes it to another process that draws pretty pictures. The input to the first process might well be JSON, but the communication within R is probably much more appropriately R data objects.

Answer (score 5):

As detailed on the [CRAN Task View for High-Performance Computing](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html), the [Rdsm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdsm/index.html) package by Norm Matloff offers shared memory communication.